# PhpPgAdmin: Edit contents

Tags: postgresql

How can I edit the contents of a table in phpPgAdmin without using SQL? Or is there an alternative tool that allows me to edit datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a primary key, then you may edit a table's contents.
This is possible on an existing table filled with contents using

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (column_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used pgadmin3 on ubuntu to work with a postgres database. It allows you to modify rows without using sql. I'm assuming phpPgAdmin is similar (but I haven't used it). I edit rows in pgadmin3 by:

1. right click table name
2. view data
3. click on the cell I want to change to edit

Here is the site for pgadmin: http://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: Hey many thanks! I didn't know that this is possible using PgAdmin. I have it installed to administrate my local dev mode database. Unfortunately it is a different version than the server requires, so it denies access to the server. For this reason, and for other reasons, I'd like to use a Web tool for the purpose of editing datasets. Therefore I use phpPgAdmin. But the editing function seems to be missing.

Comment: My PgAdmin tool doesn't provide an edit function. It begins to dawn on me it might have something to do with the particular table. I suspect the missing primary key is to blame for it...